# Ignoring the first bit using bitwise compare with permission model

Tags: java, algorithm, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I have the bits 101 and 110. I want to compare using some bitwise operator ignoring the first bit like 01 and 10.

Example:

```
I have:
101
110
===
01 & 10 <- How I want to consider
x00 <- The result I want
```

or

```
10110
11011
=====
0110 & 1011 <- How I want to consider
x0010 <- The result I want
```

How could I achieve this using bitwise operators in java?

Details:

- The first bit will always be 1.
- The other bits are variable. Both
  sides of the comparison will have the same number of bits.
- I want to detect just how to make the comparison considering the other bits and
  ignoring the first.

Use case:

- I have 2 permission values. The first is 5/101 (The permission required) and the second is 6/110 (The permission the user has).
- Excluding the first block, which will always be 1, I want to compare the third block that represents a certain permission rule in the system (using bitwise).
- "The permission required" bitmask means:

  - `1` - An always fixed value I use to be able to consider the left padding zeroes (unless there is another way to achieve this);
  - `0` - Another permission rule useless for this comparison (let's call permission 1);
  - `1` - The needed permission for the current permission rule (let's call permission 2).
- "The permission the user has" means:

  - `1` - A fixed value to be striped out;
  - `1` - Represents the value of the user for the permission 1;
  - `0` - Represents the value of the user for the permission 2. The permission 2 has the value 1 but the user has 0 then he is NOT allowed to the required action. The opposite would be ALLOWED to execute the action.

Any better solution for this case will be considered a correct answer also.

Comment: Do you require a fixed number of bits, or is it somehow variable?

Comment: It can have any number of bits, I just want to consider all the others except the first.

Comment: How do you know the number of bits? Or you want to cut the highest bit of *either* numbers? Or it is true that the highest bit is equal in both numbers?

Comment: @FagnerBrack a binary number can have any number of bits.  You have to be more specific.

Comment: @GaborSch that would make the problem far more complex, requiring base 2 log or shifts to determine the first bit that's on.

Comment: @PeterWooster Yep. And if you see his examples, the required result is also some kind of `xor`ing of the 2 operands, and after `xor`ing with `1`s in the lower bits.

Comment: @gaborsch  It looks like he wants bitwise equals which is ! a ^ b, that's why I suggested that he try a few examples

Comment: I updated the question, I hope it is more clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: @fagnerbrack re. Edited version, as asked before how do you determine the number of bits to use?

Comment: @FagnerBrack What result you expect from `0` and `0` as two operand bits?

Comment: @PeterWooster the highest bit determines the length, and the highest bit is the the same for both numbers

Comment: @fagnerbrack bitwise operators work on integer values, so you won't have just 5 bits, you'll have 32 bits to work with.

Comment: @PeterWooster Lets assume it has 32 bits but the left padding zeroes are ommited. @GaborSch I expect `0` and `0` as `1` and `0` and `1` as `0`. Is this you are asking for?

Comment: @gaborsch so you mean the first bit that's on, determining that isn't easy.  We really need the real use case for this, all else is speculation.

Comment: @FagnerBrack Is is possible to know the number of useful bits? Are they predetermined?

Comment: I updated with the use case, perhaps I am trying to achieve something that is teorically wrong.

Comment: @FagnerBrack It may be good, depending on your data storage strategy, but it is a different story than it was before...

Comment: What do you mean by 3/110 ?

Comment: @PeterWooster That was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: You can find a number of bitwise algorithms here with detailed explanation and junit test case for each: http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/bitwise/msb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the number of useful bits (e.g `numofbits = 5`) then the bitmask for the expression is:

```
bitmask = (1 << numofbits) - 1
```

If you don't know the `numofbits`, just make a loop with `num = num >> 1`, and count the iteration until you got `num == 0`.

For the use case:

```
result = (req_roles & user_roles) & (bitmask >> 1)
```

This simply `and`s the role bits, ans cuts the upper bit (which is always 1)

---

Previous answer for previous question :) :

If you know the bitmask for the highest number (e.g. `bitmask = 0x1f`  (`11111` in bits)) then you want the result of the following expression:

```
result = (a ^ b) ^ (bitmask >> 1)
```

What does it do?

- Compares all bits, the equal bits will be 0
- Reverts all lower bits, so equal bits will be 1 (leaves the high bit out, so it will remain 0)

Comment: Note, this will work, but you need to know the number of useful bits, if not the answer is much more complex.  You can find the first bit in use by or'ing the arguments and the shifting that to the right in a loop until you get zero. The count is one more than the number of useful bits.

Answer (score 3):

Just 'and' the arguments with a mask that has the first bit off, eg `011 & arg` before you compare them.

Edit: after restated question.

The alternative is to use role based permissions, these are far more flexible and easier to understand than Boolean permission strings.  They are also self documenting.  Bit string based permissions are rarely used except where memory or disk space are at a premium, like when Unix was developed back in the early '80s or in embedded systems.

Comment: You can also just mask the result of the comparison, so the mask is applied only once.

Comment: Ok but can I take the first bit off when comparing using bitwise? If I do need to take the first bit off it is quite simple to use an 'and' but I want to try this without messing with the bits as string.

Comment: There is no need to mess with the bits as a string, just use Boolean logic.

Comment: Can you give me a snippet using the examples above? I think I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: If masking the result you will need to use and to make it false or or to make it true, depends on what you want.

Comment: Can you give me a snippet using the examples above? I think I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve, just try a few examples and see what you get.

Comment: Hi @PeterWooster, I already have thought about the alternative solution, but the bits will be properly wrapped under intuitive classes with unit tests, so it will very easy to understand and keep consistency. The motivation around the use of bits is that I can create new rules without messing with the db structure (and the permission will be persisted in one or more fields in the user table, which will lead to fast access when the user is indexed).

Comment: Role based permission is usually the modern best practice and doesn't need schema changes to add more roles, there is a table of roles, and either a many-to-one or many-to-many relationship between users and roles. It also allows for groups that have particular sets of roles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// tester 1
int x, y, z, mask;
x = 0x05; // 101
y = 0x06; // 110
mask = getMask(x, y);
z = (mask & (x & y));
System.out.println(String.format("mask: %x result: %x", mask, z));

// tester 2    
int x, y, z, mask;
x = 0x16; // 10110
y = 0x1B; // 11011
mask = getMask(x, y);
z = (mask & (x & y));
System.out.println(String.format("mask: %x result: %x", mask, z));

private int getMask(final int x, final int y) {
    int mask = findHighOrderOnBit(x, 0);
    mask = findHighOrderOnBit(y, mask) - 1;
    return mask;
}

private int findHighOrderOnBit(final int target, final int otherMask) {
    int result = 0x8000;
    for (int x = 0; x != 16; x++) {
        if ((result & target) > 0)
            break;
        result >>= 1;
    }
    if (otherMask > result)
        result = otherMask;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @GaborSch - This is an example - change types as necessary - add error checking as necessary etc etc

Comment: You don't need to call findHighOrderBit twice, just or the arguments.

Comment: @PeterWooster - +1 - Good observation...I didn't think of that. Thanks.